# jQuery UI resizable/selectable not working in Backbone View

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, backbone-views, jquery-ui-resizable, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a view for my model, and in the initialization I use the following code

```
initialize: function (){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); 
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        this.$el.draggable({
            opacity: 0.5,
            containment: "parent"
        });
        this.$el.resizable();
        this.$el.selectable();
    },
```

Although draggable works, resizable and selectable do not (I haven't tested other jQuery UI interactions to check if they work). I tried placing `this.$el.resizable` inside the render function, but that wouldn't work either. I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 (I do include the necessary jquery-ui.css in my html). When the view renders, I inspect the element in my browser and it does indeed have a class of `ui.draggable, ui.resizable` and `ui.selectable` as it is supposed to, yet it's only draggable.

Trying to work around this issue, I've used CSS3 property `resize: both` in the class of the  element I want to resize and it works just fine, but I'd really like to utilize jQuery UI for resizing, and I'm curious why it won't work.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: Added jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/IgnorantUser/u7JkX/ the problem described is in the initialization of the `ButtonInCanvas` backbone view

Comment: When is the element being inserted into the DOM?

Comment: you can check out the jsfiddle, but the element gets appended to the DOM once a 'drop' event has occured. The drop occurs in the CanvasView, but utilizing a method called passDrop, I pass the drop event (along with the coordinates) to the draggable "ButtonInToolbar" that was dropped into the canvas. Then with dropHandler method I append a new "ButtonInCanvas" into the DOM

Comment: Should I report a bug on this? From what I've read, previous versions of jQuery UI had issues with event delegation, maybe I stumbled upon a bug?

Comment: also tested with jQuery 1.9.0 and jQuery UI 1.10.0 and the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so, apparently using `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));` in my render function on the `ButtonInCanvas` view was causing the problems. The aforementioned gets the "caption" attribute of the model, and passes it into the view as html content.

There solution is to put `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));` in the init function.
In case it's needed to be done in the render function, there should be another div, within the one we want to resize, that will get the caption property from the model. In the following JSBIN you can see a solution using a div inside the button. (thanks to user shoky, from the #jquery freenode irc channel for the implementation and his heads up)
http://jsbin.com/uxequq/1/edit

I don't really understand why the problem was occurring though (maybe `this.template(this.model.toJSON())` in my render function, was causing a re-rendering of the view?) so feel free to point me out why, and help me understand further!

Cheers!

Comment: since you change the html of the element which has ui-selectable or ui-resizable, the selectable and resizable need to be updated or re-applied. Because all the html which the selectable / resizable were based on (and had applied events to) has been removed or completely altered